# SQL : Error 1064 in my query, i cannot find why

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I've got this to create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `create_account`
   AFTER INSERT
   ON
       `Client`
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET
       @lastID = (
           SELECT C.idClient
           FROM CLIENT as C
           ORDER BY C.idClient
               DESC
           LIMIT 1
       );
       SET 
       @iban = ('FR1330010000019111679074293');

   SELECT IF(
                  LENGTH(@iban) < 11,
                  CONCAT(
                          REPEAT('0', (11 - LENGTH(@iban))),
                          @iban
                      ),
                  @iban = @iban
              );
   INSERT INTO `Compte`(`idCompte`,
                        `numeroCompte`,
                        `soldeCompte`,
                        `idClientCompte`,
                        `statusCompte`)
   VALUES (NULL, @iban, '0', @lastId, '0');
END
```

And MySQL returns me

> 1064 - Syntax error near '' on line 14"

Someone have explanation?

Thank you all. I work to resolve it yet.

Comment: Did you remember your `DELIMITER` statement before attempting to create the trigger?

Comment: @Nick yes "DELIMITER |"

Comment: You seem to be missing a `FROM` clause for the `SELECT IF (LENGTH(@iban) < 11...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you wanted something like this ?
If yes, then additional info: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php

The IF function does not need SELECT clause.
I have tested it here: [TEST](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8c378fe46fff6150d3effa71ac5eab9)

```
CREATE TRIGGER `create_account`
   AFTER INSERT
   ON
       `Client`
   FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   SET
       @lastID = (
           SELECT C.idClient
           FROM Client C
           ORDER BY C.idClient
               DESC
           LIMIT 1
       );
       SET 
       @iban = ('FR1330010000019111679074293');

   set @iban = IF(
                  LENGTH(@iban) < 11,
                  CONCAT(
                          REPEAT('0', (11 - LENGTH(@iban))),
                          @iban
                      ),
                  @iban
              );


   INSERT INTO Compte(idCompte,
                      numeroCompte,
                      soldeCompte,
                      idClientCompte,
                      statusCompte)
   VALUES (NULL, @iban, '0', @lastId, '0');

END;
/
```

Comment: Okay, all is working well. Thx for all ! I was close ... but didn't read the doc on the right way !

Comment: @FrenchyCoder I do not understand why people do this. Your question is `Error 1064 in my query, i cannot find why`. I have resolved your error. I do not know and can not know what other plans you have with this trigger. I am sure there are some thing everyone can do in a better way but maybe you have just began to create your trigger...This was not a question... Why did you removed a correct answer from my answer ?

Comment: what i remove ? i dont understand what you mean ... is my only 2nd question in Stackoverflow. Maybe i do something wrong on this post ?

Comment: okay i uderstand what you mean ( the green V on the left ), i add it again. I know i can't add this to all the other answer !

Comment: Yes, and when you will have some reputation points you will be able to give a vote up to the answers that helped you even just a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below snippet, basically you need to use DELIMITER otherwise mysql will start processing with the first `;`. In addition, you cant use select statements in triggers, you should always use `select into` and finally I think that you `if` statements is not working as expected it always return 1.

```
   DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `create_account` AFTER INSERT ON `Client` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
      SELECT C.idClient into @lastID FROM Client as C ORDER BY C.idClient DESC LIMIT 1;
      SELECT 'FR1330010000019111679074293' into @iban;

      SELECT IF(
               LENGTH(@iban) < 11,
               CONCAT(
                       REPEAT('0', (11 - LENGTH(@iban))),
                       @iban
                   ),
               @iban = @iban
           ) into @iban;

      INSERT INTO `Compte`(`idCompte`,
                        `numeroCompte`,
                        `soldeCompte`,
                        `idClientCompte`,
                        `statusCompte`)
      VALUES (NULL, @iban, '0', @lastId, '0');

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

An `INSERT` trigger without referencing `new` is quite suspect.

Your question should explain the logic you want to implement, but I think it is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `reate_account
    AFTER INSERT ON Client
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @iban = 'FR1330010000019111679074293';

    INSERT INTO Compte (numeroCompte, soldeCompte, idClientCompte, statusCompte)
        SELECT LPAD(@iban, 11, '0'), '0', new.idClient, '0'
        FROM DUAL
        WHERE LENGTH(@iban) < 11;
END;
```

Your trigger is much more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Yeah i've added new.idClient insted of @lastId ... but after posting my code here.
But good point, thx !

Comment: @FrenchyCoder . . . I'm surprised you unaccepted this answer.  It is a much simpler solution to your problem.